# C language:scanning of input string is skipped inside for loop

Tags: c, loops

Whenever the code is executed, the contents inside the for loop are not executing for the first time, i.e., when i=0. But the loop executes after i=0, i.e., for i=1,2,3,..n-1. Can anyone explain what's wrong here?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    char string[30][100];
    int n,i;
    scanf("%d",&n);
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
       gets(string[i]);
       printf("%s\n",string[i]);
    }
    getch();
    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Comment: `scanf("%d",&n);getchar();//for eat newline`

Comment: Or just add a space after the `scanf` format code (i.e. `"%d "`)

Comment: @JoachimPileborg `scanf("%d\n",&n);`  will do the same ?

Comment: Oh, and stop using `gets`. The function has even been removed from the latest C standard. Use [`fgets`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) instead.

Comment: @Dabo Yes, `scanf` consider any whitespace characters as a whitespace character. It doesn't matter if it's a newline, a tab, a space (or anything else that `isspace` returns non-zero for).

Comment: If a program is interactive, do **not** leave a trailing white space in a format such as `"%d "` because that trailing space won't allow `scanf()` to return until the hapless user types a non-space (non-tab, non-newline) character after the number.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg then `"%d\n"` is more general solution ?

Comment: @Dabo No not really. A space is a space is a space... *Any* space is good to use and all spaces are equal.

Comment: No; `"%d\n"` is isomorphic with `"%d "`; any white space in a `scanf()` format is equivalent to optional white space in the input stream.  The difficulty with trailing white space in the format is that `scanf()` can't tell it's reached the end of the white space until it reads something that is not white space.  Either use `fgets()` to read lines and `sscanf()` to parse them, or gobble the remainder of the line with some sort of loop (reading a single character isn't guaranteed to be sufficient; the user might have typed a space after the number).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{
   fflush(stdin);   //Clears the buffer.insert this here.
   gets(string[i]);
   printf("%s\n",string[i]);
}
```

After execution of `scanf("%d",&n);` you are leaving `'\n'`(when you press Enter key at the end) character in buffer.Which should be cleared before execution of any other input operation.`fflush(stdin)` will clear the keyboard buffer. There are many other ways to do it.But using `fflush(stdin)` is easy for beginners.

Comment: You can only use `fflush(stdin)` reliably on Windows.  Elsewhere, it is undefined behaviour — the C standard says (ISO/IEC 9899:2011 §7.21.5.2 The `fflush` function): _If stream points to an output stream or an update stream in which the most recent
operation was not input, the `fflush` function causes any unwritten data for that stream
to be delivered to the host environment to be written to the file; otherwise, the behavior is
undefined._

Comment: Also, a program can ***never*** use `gets()` safely.  It cannot protect itself from misuse or abuse.  One of the attacks used by the first Internet Worm (search on Google for 'morris internet worm'; it happened in 1988) exploited code that used `gets()`.  It is no longer standard C (it was removed from C11, for good reason).

Answer (score 0):

you can either try leaving a space after the scanf so the system pauses there instead of automatic increment the reason for this is after you press enter for the value of n , theres no system pause and one of the i values from loop is automatically considered as entered by the system :

```
scanf("%d ", &n);
```

or make the loop be from 0 till equal to n which will still skip a number but at the same time add 1 just to keep the loop equal to the input "n" u give

```
for(i=0;i<=n;i++)
```

bear in mind that the first option is much wiser to use since you might need to use the "n" in some other part of the program as well.

Comment: If a program is interactive, do **not** leave a trailing white space in a format such as `"%d "` because that trailing space won't allow `scanf()` to return until the hapless user types a non-space (non-tab, non-newline) character after the number.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler you are right about that thanks for mentioning it, do you know if theres any other way than clearing the buffer?

Comment: If worst comes to worst: `void gobble_to_newline(FILE *fp) { int c; while ((c = getc(fp)) != EOF && c != '\n') ; }`, maybe written as an inline function tuned to standard input only: `static inline void gobble_stdin_to_newline(void) { int c; while ((c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n') ; }`.  In my code, the semicolon after the `while` condition would be on a line of its own to emphasize that the loop body is empty.  It's hard to show that in a comment.